# 130W fixture containing 160 RGB LEDs - what LEDs could they be?

Tags: voltage, power, led, rgb

I apologize for this very stupid question, but I'm diving head-first into electronics and I am sort of confused.  I'm hoping some experts' answers will at least give me more terminology, concepts, and electronics to look up and study (LOL).

What kind of RGB LEDs exist that you can combine 160 of them into a light fixture that runs at maximum 130 W?  All of the RGB (or RGBW) LEDs I see run at about 9-14 V per diode (like CREE XPE2 or XMLs, or even 5mm RGD LEDs), which makes sense because each LED generally about 3V it seems.  A 130 W fixture with 160 RGB LEDs means about 0.8W per LED...so with my limited understanding, what am I missing? (Again, I apologize for this kind of ignorant question.)

I'm not trying to build this light, I'm just trying to understand how you could combine 160 LEDs into a light that's rated by the manufacturer at 130W.  I am building my own light, but it's not a replica of this one...this is just a point of trying to understand RGB LEDs better.

Comment: I'm confused about what you want to know. I've re-read it several times and your "facts" and other commentary leave me without anything much to hang a thought on. For example, you mention XPE2 which is a system that includes two LEDs with operating currents different from the third (the red.) You aren't supposed to operate them in series and that is the only way you could come up with that voltage range.

Comment: Output power details are not clear. You say that it is 130W. But is it total (i.e. R+G+B) or is it for each of R, G and B (i.e. total ~400W)? There are some other details that must be taken into account before electronics: Environment, heat transfer etc.

Comment: If you have control over the current you can combine 1,000 LEDs into one fixture and have it run at 100W. It may not be brighter than 100 LEDs at 100W but maybe it fits the design better. Maybe explain a bit more about what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, I'm sorry I'm not very clear.  With this example, I'm just trying to understand how it could work.  Your explanation helps a bit. If I understand properly, you don't HAVE to drive all he LEDs (in series) at their max current.  You could drive them much lower.  And it could be better design because maybe more even light spread?  If I got it right, then yours would be (I guess) the answer to this question.

Comment: @RohatKılıç, I'm sorry I didn't explain well.  It's 130 W for the entire fixture.  The fixture itself is made of 160 RGD LEDs (so I guess each one is R+G+B combined, maybe something like the CREEs that combine 3 diodes on a single board).  I would like to know more about the other details that matter...but I suspect maybe Spehro has answered it (yes, it really was that basic I guess...)

Comment: @jonk, I'm sorry for not being clear.  I think Spehro has answered what I was after, but I would like to understand better what you say about the RGB XPE2s.  I'm not building the 160 LED light; I'm building a 12-LED one; I've been researching to prepare. I was planning to wire each of the colors on a separate circuit - so a series of G's, etc., and wire a potentiometer in each series so I can dim them independently.  But I want them all to connect to the same power supply, if possible (one plug to AC) - to ensure safe power supply, I should sum V*Amp for all LEDs on all circuits, right?

Comment: 1) To summarize just because an LED is rated for e.g. 300mA it does not mean you have to drive them at that current. Total heat dissipation and cooling also is a factor. 2) It is Not feasible to regulate the current with a simple potentiometer in series: it will go up in smoke when you run enough current through it. (Been there some years ago). You will need a constant current LED driver.

Comment: @Jess Your added thoughts help me. Thanks. Yes, you will want to have separate current regulation for each color. So separate them. You can also use PWM for dimming once you've established the current for 100%. So yes, use one potentiometer for each color to set the maximum current and use PWM to dim, from there. Also, by balancing the three currents you can set an acceptable "white." The current sources will need to be capable of the maximum voltage needed.

Comment: @JakobHalskov - thanks!  I am currently looking for a constant current driver that suits the circuit...I will probably be posting another question soon with my circuit diagram and asking for some sort of additional advice, ha!  If you want to make your comments an answer, I will accept it so we can close out the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LEDs can of course be run at lower current than their maximum rating. This can prolong their life time and be due to thermal (cooling) reasons.

It is Not feasible or efficient to regulate the current with a simple potentiometer in series: it will go up in smoke when you run enough current through it.